# How to setup local environment to run on https

Tags: reactjs, https, ssl-certificate, localhost, mkcert

I am trying to run my React application via https local. I have followed the steps of this [tutorial](https://web.dev/how-to-use-local-https/), have installed `mkcert` correctly and the root of my project currently looks like this:

```
|-- my-react-app
    |-- package.json
    |-- localhost.pem
    |-- localhost-key.pem
    |--...
```

And my package.json file looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=localhost.pem SSL_KEY_FILE=localhost-key.pem react-scripts start",
    ...
```

Yet when I run npm start I receive this error:

`'HTTPS' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I also tried creating a `.env` file in the root and adding the variables like this:

```
HTTPS=true
SSL_CERT_FILE=localhost.pem
SSL_KEY_FILE=localhost-key.pem
```

However when I run the app this way I receive a warning to say my connection is not secure.

I have spent time googling the errors and so far still unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to amend my package.json file to look like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=localhost.pem&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=localhost-key.pem&&react-scripts start",
    ...
```

This produced a `RangeError: Invalid typed array length: -4095` on start. Upgrading my react scripts to the latest version with `npm install --save react-scripts@latest` solved that.

I now have a secure connection on my localhost. Hope this helps someone else out in the future.